# primefaces datatable column display text in many lines

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I inserted a text using primefaces inputtextArea like this :
"test (enter key)
test"

When I display it in datatable column i get this :
"test test"

I tried with escape = false but no change :(

this is my code :

For input :

```
<p:inputTextarea value="#{mybean.mytext}" cols="90" rows="6" maxlenght="500"/>
```

For output :

```
<p:column headerText="Test" width="400" styleClass="vertAlign">
    <h:outputText id="obs" value="#{mybeanList.mybean.mytext}"/>
</p:column>
```

Any idea on how to achieve it ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your answer might be found inhere:

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7455

You simply need to replace all `\n` values into `<br />` tags